# getting a ModuleNotFoundError on Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have install ed Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab on a virtual env
and all librarys that I wanto to use including Pandas

after importing Pandas I get an  `ModuleNotFoundError`

I installed Pandas again but got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install a kernel inside the venv with

`ipython kernel install --user --name=.venv`

and select the kernel for your notebook

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first inside your environment if the module is present.
if you are using conda.

```
conda activate your_env_name
pip list
```

and see if the pandas is present. If not,

```
conda activate your_env_name
pip install pandas
```

and than see if that is available. if not

```
conda activate your_env_name
pip install notebook
pip install pandas
```

This should work